# Firebase Inapp Messaging Image

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-in-app-messaging

I am new to Firebase and I have integrated in-app messaging in both ios and android and are working. But the in app message images and card are behaving differently in ios as show in the attachments. I need the image content size of the ios image to fill, remove the extra white space in between the title and the buttons as shown in android screenshot. I am using the same image and every other info is same in both ios and android. But still I am facing this issue and not able to find solution anywhere. Can anyone help me out with this, please? image 1 is from iOS and image 2 is from Android.
[image: 1) iOS Screenshot of inapp message][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Uvs0.jpg)

[image: 2 android Screenshot of inapp message]